# Unable to fetch document in flutter firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a field with name boughtBy, it contains all the ids of the user who have bought the coupons. So, I am trying to show only those coupons which don't have the currentUsers id in the field boughtBy which is an array.

**My Code:-**

```
QuerySnapshot snapshotForCoupons=await couponsReference.where('visibility',isEqualTo: true).where('boughtBy',whereNotIn: [currentUser.id]).limit(10).get();
```

but the problem is it is still showing the coupon which contains the currentUser id.

Comment: I thinnk the eroor is `.where('boughtBy',whereNotIn: [currentUser.id])` here the currentUser is an array and you can't perform array operation with `whereNotIn` , the fesable soulution would be to use `.arrayContains` after fetching the array maybe.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/samples/firestore-query-filter-not-in#firestore_query_filter_not_in-nodejs) your query should be written like this:

```node
QuerySnapshot snapshotForCoupons = await couponsReference.where('visibility',isEqualTo: true).where('boughtBy', 'not-in', [currentUser.id]).limit(10).get();
```